# Using customXmlParts with Excel Add-in with the Office.js API

Tags: office-js

I'm starting to work with the new Office.js Add-ins API with Excel and I'm trying to persist my add-in state nicely.  The old VSTO Add-in API had CustomXMLParts, and I see that there is a Office.context.document.customXmlParts but according to the docs (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/customxmlparts.customxmlparts) it only works with Word.  Anybody know how to do this with Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CustomXML parts for Excel are coming very soon, as part of the `ExcelApi 1.5` requirement set.  See https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/ExcelJs_OpenSpec for details.

Baring any unforeseen circumstances, "very soon" means that it should be roughly a month away from being available on Insider Fast builds, and 1 - 1.5 months from that point till it rolls out to broad production.

Comment: The docs/specs  can be found here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/ExcelJs_OpenSpec 
See here for a reference implementation that shows how custom XML parts can be used in an add-in (we’re adding readme page shortly).

Comment: The custom XML parts are part of Build 1702. If you have this version you'd be able to test using the BETA CDN. The GA release will likely take place in next few weeks. See the link github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/ExcelJs_OpenSpec for details on accessing BETA functionality.